# why is it moving the pointer into a register and not just using the pointer directly? "movl record_buffer_ptr, %eax"

Tags: assembly, x86

the title says it all, why is it moving the pointer into a register and not just using the pointer directly?

**assembly in book "Programming From Ground Up Chapter 9":**

```
movl record_buffer_ptr, %eax
addl $RECORD_FIRSTNAME, %eax
```

**what i'm suggesting, haven't tested rn ( don't have my laptop ):**

```
addl $RECORD_FIRSTNAME, record_buffer_ptr
```

Comment: Your way modifies the global variable, and you still don't have the pointer in a register where you could dereference it.  But yes, what would be a valid instruction that would produce the same result (in a different place).

Comment: Presumably the next thing the book is going to show you is `mov ptr, %eax` / `mov RECORD_FIRSTNAME(%eax), %edx` to actually load part of the record into another register.  (or maybe a `movzbl` to load 1 byte, if it's a `struct{ char firstname[10]; char lastname[10]; }` or something, rather than holding pointers.)